# Problem with tocloft, minitoc and bold math mode

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, bold, tocloft, minitoc

To ensure **equations in headings are written bold** as well I have added the following command to my document:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
```

This works very well until I combine it with `minitoc` and `tocloft`. While the global TOC is printed correctly, the minitoc's section equations are written bold.

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% --- ENSURE THAT BOLD FACE IS NOT IGNORED BY EQUATION ENVIRONMENTS ---
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
% --- END ---

\begin{document}
  % initialize minitoc:
  \dominitoc

  % TOC:
  \tableofcontents

  % dummy structure:
  \chapter{Math, hurray!}
  \minitoc

  \section{Math makes me happy!}
    \subsection{$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ -- The Pythagorean Theorem}
    \subsection{Who want to live without math?}

  \section{$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ -- Halleluja}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

---

[image: Global TOC]

...

[image: Chapter with strange minitoc]

---

Can you explain me or even solve this strange behaviour?

Comment: Try `\g@addto@macro\normalfont{\mathversion{normal}}`

Comment: Great job! I have thought of something like that but didn't know how to write it. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works only as expected if the bold font ends at the end of some group. It doesn't work if the code does something like

```
\bfseries some text \normalfont some text
```

or

```
\bfseries some text \mdseries some text
```

You will have to issue a `\mathversion{normal}` in such cases. E.g. in your example with

```
\g@addto@macro\normalfont{\mathversion{normal}}
```